# Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] when trying to select from db

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple select using sqlQuery and I am trying to map it to an entity. I do not understand what the problem is or what can I do about it and  I tried multiple sources from this site without any result

function that takes the records

````
    public List<MYTABLE> getRecords(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, Map<String, Object> filters) throws DBEDatabaseException {   

        
        try {
            EntityManager em = getMyEmOrThrow();
            SQLQuery q = em.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE A where A.status = '1000'");
            q.addEntity("A", MYTABLE.class);
            q.setFirstResult(first);
            q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
            
            List<MYTABLE> results = q.list();
            
            return  results;
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            throw new MyCustomException("Failure in getting records from table MYTABLE : ", e);
    }


```
Entity - **getters and setters and rest of the columns omitted** 
@Entity(name = "MYTABLE")
@Table(schema = "MYSCHEMA", name = "MYTABLE")
public class MYTABLE implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (6)") // this column is the problem
    private Timestamp timestamp;

}


```
THIS DOESN'T WORK AS WELL

     @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (6)")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date timestamp;



[Records in db look like this][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahDmJ.png
````

Comment: The problem is because of the locale. The expected format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]` whereas the format in which the data has been stored is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[,fffffffff]`. By the way, why are you using the outdated and broken `java.util.Date` based API? I recommend you stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I can not use that API because the project I work for is an old one. How can I solve this problem for this? Make a getter that returns a string like the one below suggested? I am a little confused about the solution

Answer (score 0):

for formatting date output you should use SimpleDateFormat,
also you could define formatter method to your entity

Comment: Where exactly can I do this? In the setter method?

Comment: no its better you have another getter that return string instead of date